Why is sequences enough in the definition of a normal family
In the definition of a normal family in complex analysis, we are concerned with a sequence of functions having a subsequence uniformly converging to a function on compact subsets of an open domain. But why using sequences is enough, when the compact-open topology is not sequential in general? Or is it actually metrizable (or sequential) in this case?
I didn't think about this when learning complex analysis, but now I'm reading about compact-open topology and this confuses me. Because it is said "a normal family is just a precompact subset in the space of cts functions under the compact-open topology". But compactness might not be sequential in that topology. Thanks in advance.

It is metrizable. You just have to take an appropriate  sequence of compact sets $K_n$ increasing to your domain and use sup over these sets to define  a metric. This is quite standard.
